# Modifying <asp:label> in form

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a form using all asp:textbox and asp:label.  Currently, I am using the RequiredFieldValidator to validate text boxes and display an error inline.  What I  am trying to do is to change the color of one of the asp:labels after validation fails for one of the textboxes fields.  Would I accomplish this with javascript, or is there any commands that can do it within asp to modify labels.  I would really appreciate any help and code examples.

Comment: is this ASP.NET or classic ASP?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that javascript is the way forward here if you don't want to postback to the server. If you use ASP.NET only the page will normally have to be posted back so that the server can change the properties of the label - not very user friendly. A colleague of mine has accomplished this very nicely using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) (a javascript libraray) but unfortunatly I don't have a copy of the code to hand. He's an SO user too so I'll pass on a link to this post for you.